# What does it mean to add a prototype to a function?

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
var x = function () {

};  
x.prototype = { abc: 25 };
```

Can someone explain to me what this means. Could this be done all inside a function without the .prototype?

```
var x = function () {
  // something here ?
};
```

Comment: The following should explain a lot:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 prototype saves memory and CPU as well as enables you to use recognizable OO patterns

Comment: You can do `this.abc = 25` inside the constructor, which is roughly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototypes are how the class model works in JavaScript - you've created a class `x` that has a property `abc` which defaults to `25`:

```
var obj = new x();
alert(obj.abc);   // 25
```

The function `x` is the class constructor, it is called when a new instance of that class is created and can initialize it. And that means of course that you can just set the `abc` property there:

```
var x = function()
{
  this.abc = 25;
};
var obj = new x();
alert(obj.abc);   // 25
```

This is supposedly the less efficient approach however:

- You have to manipulate each object created rather than setting the property on the prototype once and forever.
- The property is stored on each object and consumes memory each time, as opposed to being stored once on the prototype.

ECMAScript Harmony has a [nicer syntax](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aclasses) for defining classes and prototypes, however this one isn't implemented in any browser yet:

```
class x {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  public abc = 25;
}
```

This is equivalent to your code defining the prototype, merely grouping related operations a little better.

Comment: So there is no way I can do this when defining the function? I need to add a prototype later?

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't call x a class though: it's a constructor

Comment: @SamanthaJ: I updated my answer. Summary: No, you cannot define constructor and prototype at once, though a better syntax is in the planning. Yes, you can define properties in the constructor but this approach has downsides.